# Why won't this Insert INTO Work ? Php

Tags: php

// This is the file that is giving the error, not the form below

```
       <?php
        // Insert Comments into Database that user provides

<?php
// Insert Comments into Database that user provides
$comm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addComment']);

// following line has changed:
$pID4 = filter_var( $_POST['pID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

$cID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['courseInfoDD']);
$username = "###";
$password = "###";
$pdo4 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=###', $username, $password);
$pdo4->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth4 = $pdo4->prepare('INSERT INTO Comment (info, pID, cID) VALUES(?,?,?);'); 
$sth4->execute(array($comm, $pID4, $cID ));

?>
```

**Form**

```
<input type='text' id='addComment' name='addComment' tabindex='3' value='Enter comment' />
<input type='hidden' name='pID' value='<?php echo $pID ?>'>
</form>
```

**ERROR Received:**

```
*No error is received upon load, but once I type something in and press enter it gives me a blank page saying 'no pID specified' ?? Please help!*
```

Comment: POST form submissions don't add anything to the URL. If you want to use URL query strings for your form submissions, change the method value in your HTML to "get". Of course, that also necessitates changing the filter you're using as well.

Comment: Show the code using this? Appreciate the reply

Comment: See @Phil Brown's answer below. :)

Comment: Please see my comment to Phil, I'm not sure how to implement the hidden input into my php file as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you'll need to add the `pID` to the request data either via the form action, though this parameter will show in the `$_GET` array instead of `$_POST`

```
<form action="inc/q/prof.php?pID=<?php echo $pID ?>" method="post">
```

or via a form element (will be part of the `$_POST` array)

```
<input type="hidden" name="pID" value="<?php echo $pID ?>">
```

Now, a further consideration...

You don't need to apply db string escaping (`mysql_real_escape_string()`) when using PDO prepared statements with bound parameters. The act of binding a parameter or value takes care of that for you.

---

To clarify my comments below, you need something like this...

Given a URL like `http://example.com/index.php?pID=842`, your form on that page should have the following hidden element

```
<input type="hidden" name="pID" value="<?php echo (int) $_GET['pID'] ?>" />
```

Comment: How do I implement the hidden input? I can just copy and paste the code in  between <form> elements, but what do I need to do for the php side? I tried just putting that hidden element in and got the same problem, that's why I ask :)

Comment: `$pID4 = filter_var( $_POST['pID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );`

Comment: The `$pID` variable in my answer is just a guess. Based on the information in your question, you could assign it using `$pID = htmlspecialchars($_GET['pID'])`. Other than that, your code is already looking for `$_POST['pID']` so you shouldn't need to change anything else

Comment: @Phil Brown Oh, duh. Looks like I get to wear the dunce cap again... :p

Comment: Check updated code, this still is not working :( . I feel like it is still losing the pID upon submission still

Comment: @user Are you assigning a value to `$pID`? See my comment above.

Comment: The pID=[somenumber] is being appended to the url.

Answer (score 0):

Two words: [GET FIREBUG](http://getfirebug.com/). Before checking your PHP script, you should check your HTML form. It's possible you're not echoing the form correctly.

I don't thinks it's safer to go with POST submissions, but definitely it's cleaner.

After you checked your form it should look like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="form-process.php">
    <input type='text' id='addComment' name='addComment' tabindex='3' value='Enter comment' />
    <input type="hidden" name="courseInfoDD" value="XXX" id="courseInfoDD">
    <input type="hidden" name="pID" value="XXX" id="pID">
</form>
```

On your submit script, you can access those parameters with $_POST. But remeber, if you have an empty value on your HTML form, it would become an empty variable.

You can do a quick echo on $pID to see their content.

@Phil Brown is right about PDO. You don't have to escape variables before sending it to the handler.

Hope it helps!

Comment: How can I do a quick echo, when this form is being submitted?